# How to find the current operation in spring

Tags: spring, jsp, struts2

I have a project in spring+sturts+hibernate.In jsp page (where i show the list of data) i have three buttons view,modify and add.I want to know which button i pressed in order to show the flow to the user. Now i use a variable named as type and update this variable to some value when i click this button.Then i  am checking this variable in the corresponding pages to show whether it is add, modify or view. I know this is not a good approach.Can any one suggest me a good one.

Comment: why don't you use `anchor` tag......or if you want button use it inside `anchor` tag like `
<a href="edit.jsp"><input type="button" value="edit"></a>`

Comment: after which you can use `simpleurlhandler` for directing it to require  controller and to the desired page...

Comment: That what I see in the application are buttons that looks like a thumbnails on the page and it will not handle data without that buttons and it on every page.

Answer (score 1):

Just use different actions for each button you have. With different actions you will be able to determine which button was pressed and show appropriate page/data.

For example in `struts.xml` file define your actions.

```
<action name="add" ...>
  <result>add_page</result>
</action>
<action name="modify" ...>
  <result>modify_page</result>
</action>
<action name="view" ...>
  <result>view_page</result>
</action>
```

And in JSP page use buttons with this actions.